# Why doesn't my closure function want to reassign its parent function variable, when within an if statment?

Tags: javascript, closures, factory

I have created this factory function that I am using for describing the game logic. I use the inner function for switching players in the game. The problem is that when I try to reassign the current player from within the inner function, it does not work. The current player never changes. I guess it is something about closure that I do not really grasp. Could you please explain to me what I am missing. Here is the piece of code I am working on:

```
const game = (() => {
    let player1 = "Jim";
    let player2 = "Mary";
    let currentPlayer = player1;

    const switchPlayers = () => { //This closure function is supposed to reassign the value of currentPlayer above. But it does not do it.
        if (currentPlayer === player1) {
            currentPlayer = player2;
        } else {
            currentPlayer = player1;
        }
        return currentPlayer;
    };

    return {currentPlayer, switchPlayers};

})();

game.switchPlayers // works as needed and switches the players every time it is invoked but does not reassign the variable within its parent function;
game.currentPlayer // does not get reassigned, when switchPlayers function is invoked, and returns player1 as was assigned at the start;
```

Comment: how do you `define/initialize` game object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code returns **value** of `currentPlayer` which is not updated when the original object's property updates. So, closure is working fine but the fact is your returned value is not pointing to the updated object, its simply a new value which will stay constant at the time of `return` statement.

You need to return the value using a function as below.

```js
let game = (() => {
  let player1 = "Jim";
  let player2 = "Mary";
  let currentPlayer = player1;

  const switchPlayers = () => { //This closure function is supposed to reassign the value of currentPlayer above. But it does not do it.
    if (currentPlayer === player1) {
      currentPlayer = player2;
    } else {
      currentPlayer = player1;
    }
    return currentPlayer;
  };
  
  const getCurrentPlayer = () => currentPlayer;

  return {
    currentPlayer,
    switchPlayers,
    getCurrentPlayer
  };

})();

game.switchPlayers();
console.log(game.currentPlayer);
console.log(game.getCurrentPlayer());
```

OR Just define the property `currentPlayer` on `this` pointer of the function and then use it as a type (using `new` keyword) as below.

```js
function GameType() {
   let player1 = "Jim";
   let player2 = "Mary";
   this.currentPlayer = player1;

   this.switchPlayers = () => { //This closure function is supposed to reassign the value of currentPlayer above. But it does not do it.
     if (this.currentPlayer === player1) {
       this.currentPlayer = player2;
     } else {
       this.currentPlayer = player1;
     }
     return this.currentPlayer;
   };
 }

let game = new GameType();

console.log(game.currentPlayer);

game.switchPlayers();
console.log(game.currentPlayer);
```

Answer (score 1):

It **does** reassign the variable.

The problem is that the object you return has properties with **copies of the values** of those variables and not references to the variables.

So `let currentPlayer` is changed but `game.currentPlayer` still contains a copy of the original value.

Get rid of the variables and just modify the object properties instead.

```js
const game = (function() {
  const player1 = "Jim";
  const player2 = "Mary";
  let o = {
    currentPlayer: player1
  };

  const switchPlayers = () => {
    if (o.currentPlayer === player1) {
      o.currentPlayer = player2;
    } else {
      o.currentPlayer = player1;
    }
    return o.currentPlayer;
  };

  o.switchPlayers = switchPlayers;
  return o;
})();

console.log(game.currentPlayer);
console.log(game.currentPlayer);
console.log(game.switchPlayers());
console.log(game.currentPlayer);
console.log(game.currentPlayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mneed to take an object reference and store the players inside, not outside, because the object does not change the state.

```js
const game = function() {
    let player1 = "Jim";
    let player2 = "Mary";
    let currentPlayer = player1;

    const
        switchPlayers = () => {
            object.currentPlayer = object.currentPlayer === player1 
                ? player2
                : player1;
            return object.currentPlayer;
        },
        object = { currentPlayer, switchPlayers };
    
    return object;
}();

console.log(game.switchPlayers());
console.log(game.currentPlayer);
console.log(game.switchPlayers());
console.log(game.currentPlayer);
```